# Proving that $\frac{x}{C-x}$ is a convex function (m/m/1 delay)

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Consider the function

$$\frac{x}{C-x} \quad (C\in\Bbb R \ \text{a constant}).$$

C>=0

How can I prove that it is a convex function?

or this $$\frac{x}{10-x}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You will have more chances to have your question answered instead of downvoted (as it happened already) if you show what you have done, where you have stuck, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is undefined at $x=C$. In all other places, show that $f''(x)>0$. Arithmetic may be easier if you prove $$f(x) = \frac{C}{C-x} - 1$$

Comment: Your f is wrong, and you (apparent) conclusion on convexity is wrong.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone just typo on $f$, corrected, thanks. I did not draw any conclusions, just explained to the OP what to establish if he wants to show this.